# The set of all strings over {0,1} that do not contain both the sequence “101” and the sequence “010”

Tags: string, set, automata

I want to write the set of all strings over {0,1} that do not contain both the sequence “101” and the sequence “010” formally.

Is that correct:

{w∈{0,1}* | ∀x,y∈{0,1}*s.t w = x101y ⇔ ∀x',y'∈ {0,1}*,w ≠ x'010y'}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write it with words, because of lack of time:

`w` in `{0,1}*` where `w` does not belong to (`x` union `y`), `x = a101b`, `y = c010d`, for any `a,b,c,d` in `{0,1}*`.